# Правильно ли я понял суть промисов?

Tags: javascript, node.js

В общем была задача передать в шаблон user.
После авторизации в сессию попадает id юзера, но для передачи полных данных в шаблон мне нужно найти в бд юзера по id и вывести render в callback-e, но в таком случае если сессия отсутствует то я получаю ошибку на клиенте и приходится делать 2 render-a. Позже понадобилось помимо user-a вывести категории и получается, что для того чтоб мне передать данные в шаблон мне нужно создать несколько callback-ов. Вариант очевидно невыносимый и я решил попробовать промисы, но до этого я совершенно не понимал где и как их использовать.

**Было:**

```
const renderIndex = (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.session.passport){
    userModel.findById(req.session.passport.user, (err, result)=>{
        try {
            user = {
                username: result.username,
                password: result.password
            }
            res.render('index', {
                title: 'Title',
                user: user,
                config: config,
            })
        } catch (e) {
            next(e)
        }
    })
    } else {
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Title',
            user: null,
            config: config,
        })
    }


}
```

**Стало:**

```
async function renderIndex (req, res, next) {
    let categories = await categoriesList()
    let user = await getUser(req, res)
    console.log(user)
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Title',
        user: user,
        config: config,
        categories: categories
    })


}
async function getUser(req, res) {
    if(req.session.passport) {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            userModel.findById(req.session.passport.user, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err)
                }
                return resolve(result)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Прошу оценить код и указать на недочеты.

Comment: 1) `async` в определении `getUser()` не нужно. 2) Вы никак не перехватываете возможные ошибки в `getUser`. 3) Что такое `userModel`? Если это то, что я подозреваю, то оно и само умеет возвращать промис, если ему не передать коллбэк.

Comment: @Yaant, не может, иначе у него не было бы параметра с коллбэком

Comment: @Yaant 1) `async` в определении `getUser()` нужно, иначе если `if(req.session.passport)` будет `false`, то функция `getUser` вернет `null`. В случае с `async` вернет `Promise<null>`. 2) какие ошибки могут быть, помимо перехваченных ТС? 3) кажется, не умеет оно в промис

Comment: @Grundy Параметр может быть необязательным, и возвращаемое значение может зависеть от его наличия. Так, например, устроен mongoose.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko 1) Действительно, не обратил внимания. Повод переделать функцию. :) 2) Так в том то и дело, что если в функции вызовется `reject()`, то снаружи будет сгенерировано исключение, которое никак не будет перехвачено. 3) Это похоже на mongoose'овскую модель, а они как раз умеют. :)

Comment: Вот так переписал:
`const getUser = async (user) => {
    try {
       return await userModel.findById(user.id)
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('User not logged')
    }
}`